# missing Drawable class - C# Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin to develop an Android app with C#, and I am trying to create an ImageView from an image in the Resource folder.

I have tried the following code:

```
var imageView =
         FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.album_cover);
        imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.sample2);
```

and I get this error: 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Drawable'

It seems that I do not have the 'Drawable' class at all. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: please go through on these documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/

Comment: Clean your solution, delete the bin and obj files, restart your visual studio and try again.